# Is there any tool or simulator for Topological quantum gates and circuits?

Tags: topological-quantum-computing

I am starting to step into the field of Topological Quantum Information and Computation and am in search of tools which I can use to directly simulate or realize these transformations in a textual or graphical manner.

Comment: Pen and paper? .

Comment: Except that? Any computational environment?

Answer (score 0):

I found below repo on github which you can check.
https://github.com/jacobmarks/QTop

QTop allows for the simulation of topologies with arbitrary code depth, qudit dimension, and error models. Currently, QTop features Kitaev quantum double models, as well as color codes in 3-regular planar tilings.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Quantum Computing Stack Exchange! Please describe more about this tool and how it fits the OP's requirements to prevent it from being a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), otherwise it may be deleted. Thank you!